# useGlobalContext().page is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

> The problem i Faceing that I,m using useContext Hook, and created a Nabvar and it,s Submenu component, Navbar is ok but while i (onMouseOver event) hover on navbar for submenu than Navbar component is Hide my Submenu Component is not working!!!!!

> ERROR like :-

```
The above error occurred in the <Submenu> component
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: _Context__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useGlobalContext().page is undefined
```

> App.js Component.

```
import Navbar from "./Component/Navbar/Navbar";
import Submenu from "./Component/Submenu/Submenu";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Submenu />
    </div>
  );
} 

export default App;
```

> Submenu.js Component.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import {useGlobalContext} from '../../Context'

const Submenu = () => {
  const {
    isSubmenuOpen,
    page: { page, links },
    location,
  } = useGlobalContext();
  const container = useRef(null);
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState("col-2");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setColumns("col-2");
    const submenu = container.current;
    const { center, bottom } = location;
    submenu.style.left = `${center}px`;
    submenu.style.top = `${bottom}px`;
    console.log(links);
    if (links.length === 3) {
      setColumns("col-3");
    }
    if (links.length > 3) {
      setColumns("col-4");
    }
  }, [page, location, links]);
  
  return (
    <aside
      className={`${isSubmenuOpen ? "submenu show" : "submenu"}`}
      ref={container}
    >
      <section>
        <h4>{page}</h4>
        <div className={`submenu-center ${columns}`}>
          {links.map((link, index) => {
            const { url, icon, label } = link;
            return (
              <a key={index} href={url}>
                {icon}
                {label}
              </a>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </section>
    </aside>
  );
};

export default Submenu;
```

> Navbar.js Component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useGlobalContext } from '../../Context'
import "./Navbar.css"

const Navbar = () => {
const {openSubmenu, closeSubmenu} = useGlobalContext();

  const displaySubmenu = (e) => {
    const page = e.target.textContent;
    const tempBtn = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const center = (tempBtn.left + tempBtn.right) / 2;
    const bottom = tempBtn.bottom - 3;
    openSubmenu(page, { center, bottom });
  };


  return (
    <nav >
    <div className="nav-center">
        <ul className="nav-links">
          <li><button className='link-btn' onMouseOver={displaySubmenu}>Home</button></li>
          <li><button className='link-btn' onMouseOver={displaySubmenu}>Service</button></li>
          <li><button className='link-btn' onMouseOver={displaySubmenu}>Product</button></li>
          <li><button className='link-btn' onMouseOver={displaySubmenu}>blog</button></li>
          <li><button className='link-btn'>register</button></li>
          <li><button className='link-btn'>login</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

> data.js

```
import { FaCreditCard, FaBook, FaBriefcase } from 'react-icons/fa';
import React from 'react';
const sublinks = [
  {
    page: 'products',
    links: [
      { label: 'payment', icon: <FaCreditCard />, url: '/products' },
      { label: 'terminal', icon: <FaCreditCard />, url: '/products' },
      { label: 'connect', icon: <FaCreditCard />, url: '/products' },
    ],
  },
  {
    page: 'developers',
    links: [
      { label: 'plugins', icon: <FaBook />, url: '/products' },
      { label: 'libraries', icon: <FaBook />, url: '/products' },
      { label: 'help', icon: <FaBook />, url: '/products' },
      { label: 'billing', icon: <FaBook />, url: '/products' },
    ],
  },
  {
    page: 'company',
    links: [
      { label: 'about', icon: <FaBriefcase />, url: '/products' },
      { label: 'customers', icon: <FaBriefcase />, url: '/products' },
    ],
  },
];

export default sublinks;
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem while consuming the useGlobalContext hook on Submenu Component. if you can provide the useGlobalContext, it can be figured out.